# Copy-Position yields incomplete FEN

Tags: feature-request, bug, pgn-viewer

I'm surprised this does not seem to have been asked, but why is it that the "Copy Position" function of the chess replayer does not include important information like whose turn it is and the castling rights and the number of moves left for the 50-move-rule to apply? Can this poor design be fixed?